# Check if date range is in month (calendar)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to check with sql if a date range (with start and end date) is in a month (regarding year). Month and year are given variables (GET-variables).

**This is my table:**

```
+----+------+-------+-----+
| id | name | start | end |
+----+------+-------+-----+
```

Because an appointment could be just one date (start and end would be the same date), I have to consider this.

**My query**

```
SELECT 
    id,
    name,
    start,
    end
FROM appointments
WHERE (MONTH(start) = ? AND YEAR(end) = ?) OR (MONTH(start) = ? AND YEAR(end) = ?)
ORDER BY start
```

The problem with this query is that it just checks the start-month and the end-month not the months between. For example if an appointment is over 5 months, this query fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know if a particular month is in the range, then I would suggest turning the dates into a YYYYMM format.  This makes the logic relatively easy to express:

```
where ?*100 + ? between year(start)*100 + month(start) and
                        year(end)*100 + month(end)
```

Comment: How can I convert the dates to YYYYMM? Maybe in the query like `DATE_FORMAT(start, 'YYYYMM') AS start2`? But this doesn't work.

Comment: @Bernd . . . That is what the arithmetic does . . . multiply the year times 100 and adds the month.  You can also use `date_format()`, because this will work for strings as well as numbers.